# Swift 5 Coordinating background tasks

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I am still trying to understand and control asynch tasks.  I have an app which is generating multiple API calls to different providers.  I could have a maximum of 367 API calls in parallel.  How can I coordinate all of these so I can know when the first one starts and the last one is completed?

With help from this forum, I can get this working with single calls, but not multiple.

My call to the API from a class is below (relevant sections, which show the use of .completion:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = components.url!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
            return
        }

        guard
            let responseData = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(AstronomicalTimesError.invalidResponse(data, response)))
            }
            return
        }

        do {
            print("Astronomical times api completed with status code ", httpResponse.statusCode)
            let astronomicalTimesResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(AstronomicalTimesResponse.self, from: responseData)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(astronomicalTimesResponse))
                //print("astronomical times loaded ", astronomicalTimesResponse)
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(jsonError))
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```

This is then called for each day in a date range.

```
repeat {
        let astronomicalTimes = AstronomicalTimes(date: astRetrievalDate, latitude: station.lat, longitude: station.long)

        astronomicalTimes.start { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let astronomicalTimesResponse):
                    let detail = DayDetails(date: astRetrievalDate, astronomicalTimes: astronomicalTimesResponse.results)
                    details.append(detail)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Astronomical Times API call from saved tides failed with error \(error)")
            }
        }
        astRetrievalDate = astRetrievalDate.dayAfter
    } while astRetrievalDate.noon <= toDate.noon

    let tideToSave = SavedTides(saveKey: key, details: details)
    savedTides.append(tideToSave)
    print("saved tide details: ", savedTides)
```

I want to build up the results in savedTides but, the all the API's complete after the assignment to savedTides so this is always empty.  Note that I will also be firing off another two separate API's to different providers so I need all of these to complete before I assign the results of all of them to an array.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter `DispatchGroup` is reasonable otherwise a serial `OperationQueue` and asynchronous `Operation`.

Comment: The phrase “when the first one starts and the last one is completed” is very confusing. What do first and last mean when things are in parallel?   Do you want to serialize them (do them in some order) or do you just want to know when they are all done?

Comment: Sorry for confusion.  I want to allow the user to enter a date range.  I then will call 3 APIs.  Two of them will take the date range and return data (corresponding to individual days).  One of the APIs can only take a single date as a parameter so i need to call it multiple times (one call for every day in the range).  I want to save the data returned by all of the calls and store it in an array sorted by day.  I will call each API sequentially, in functions and loops.  I want to collect the data they return and load into the array.  Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you have a look at promises? so you can fire other call whenever the others that you need to complete before are done.

https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

You can group multiple promises in an array and fire them all together, or maybe a `DispatchGroup` could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  DispatchGroup was the answer.  I was really struggling to understand how to use it from the apple documentation, however I came across this excellent tutorial and all was clear.  [How to use DispatchGroup in Swift 4.2](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-dispatchgroup-in-swift-4-2-similar-to-async-await-in-javascript-62a2ff04e51e)